# C memory location of the array name

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I'm confused about how C stores in memory an array. From the example bellow the address of str1 is equal to its value. Whit this I was interpreting the result as: the memory address &str1 contains the value of the address itself. But this can not be the case because from other examples I saw the address of str1 contains the first value of the string, which in this case is "H".

So my question can be: where is the address of str1 stored?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
  char str1[] = "Hello World";
  printf("%d %d %c\n",&str1,str1,str1[0] );
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: When you say "address of `str1`", what do you exactly mean by that?

Comment: `str1` is an array so using that name as you do here results in its address. `&str1` evaluates to the same value as `str1`. `str1[0]` is the vaue of its first element.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie `&str1` and `str1` evaluate to the same value but different types.

Comment: @EugeneSh, correct, but not relevant here. (Updated my comment)

Comment: For `int b;` , where is `&b` stored?  Once you can answer this question,  it is in fact the same answer as for `&a`.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you must use `%p` format specifier to print an address (pointer).

That being said, quoting `C11`, chapter §6.3.2.1

> Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` operator, the `_Alignof` operator, or the
>   unary `&` operator, or is a string literal used to initialize an array, an expression that has
>   type ‘‘array of type’’ is converted to an expression with type ‘‘pointer to type’’ that points
>   to the initial element of the array object and is not an lvalue.

So, basically,

```
  printf("%p", str1);
  printf("%p", &str1[0]);
```

are the same.

Now, coming to the part of `&str1`, well, the type is different. It is of type `char [<array size>]`.